# laravel - trying to set up virtual host on using xampp on mac

Tags: php, laravel

i am using laravel to create my website. I am using xampp but unable to connect website to the server.. i am getting the following error. Can anyone help? I am using mac by the way.

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.9
>   mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Comment: Please post the text of the error. Screenshots are usually not encouraged on S.O. unless they can add value which is not conveyable by text. Also, links to other sites could go out of date, and the context is completely lost then.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I'm new here, text of error added above

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access via the browser or cURL? There should be  a default directory for Apache which will not yield this error if the web server is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running on a MacOs you should look at [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/valet) which is for me the easiest and cleanest way to setup a Laravel application on your local machine.

Comment: i have tried to install but getting this error Error: Failure while executing; git clone
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core exited with 128.

Comment: Do you have installed `Homebrew` ? What is your MacOs version ?

Comment: mac version is 10.11.6 .. and no when i run the command it states the error above

Comment: You should first run `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` to install homebrew.

Comment: this is returned "==> You are using macOS 10.11.
==> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
This installation may not succeed.
After installation, you will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew\'s GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version"
 Do i need to run a software update?

Comment: You should always keep your system up to date yes !

Comment: Np update available apparently - i fixed it by running the following command - git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core --depth=1